# Error in terminal when running create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React application via `npm create-react-app my app` and I get this error:

[image]

I've installed `npm install command`. What is the problem with what I'm doing?

Comment: Try removing the space between `my` and `app`

Comment: Try adding the ReactJS dependencies to your `package.json` file (don't forget to run `npm install` afterwards). And then try `npm run -- create-react-app my app`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

`npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start`

You can't have spaces in the app name